# R using fortify to project shapefile on google map gives wrong results

Tags: shapefile, r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have a shapefile that looks like this

```
> str(FieldsMap)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ id  : int [1:3] 3 2 1
  .. ..$ Attr: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3 2 1
  ..@ polygons   :List of 3
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 8.6 47.7
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 5.88e-08
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:6, 1:2] 8.6 8.61 8.61 8.61 8.6 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 8.6 47.7
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 5.88e-08
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 8.61 47.68
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 1.41e-06
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:15, 1:2] 8.61 8.61 8.61 8.61 8.61 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 8.61 47.68
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "1"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 1.41e-06
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 1
  .. .. .. .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygon' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ labpt  : num [1:2] 8.61 47.68
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ area   : num 1.11e-06
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ hole   : logi FALSE
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ ringDir: int 1
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..@ coords : num [1:17, 1:2] 8.61 8.61 8.61 8.61 8.61 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int 1
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 8.61 47.68
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "2"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 1.11e-06
  ..@ plotOrder  : int [1:3] 2 3 1
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 8.6 47.68 8.61 47.68
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

No I want to plot the polygons with `ggmap` on a google map so I run:

```
MapExtent<-bbox(FieldsMap)
Map<-get_map(MapExtent,maptype="hybrid")
mapTransform<-fortify(FieldsMap,region="id")
p1<-ggmap(Map)+geom_polygon(data=mapTransform,aes(long,lat,group=as.factor(group)),fill="green",color="green")
p1
```

However, the polygons do not have the right shape after fortifying and are not exactly at the right place( a few hundred meters of). Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this? Plotting `plot(FieldsMap)` gives the right shape of the polygon. I also noticed that after fortifying there is sometimes no polygon plotted using another shapefile. Displaying both shapefiles in QGIS works as it should, so I supect `fortify` to cause the problem, because looking at the plot I get the impression that sometimes points are missing or are connected in the wrong order.

Comment: When posting a question please do not imply that the software/library is producing incorrect results unless you have a reproducible example that illustrates a potential bug. Commonly, ~99% of the time an OP implies that the software is incorrect it is user error. Developers work hard, and often for free, and do not need users intimating that their code is producing incorrect results unless there is ample proof of a bug that can be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

If your polygons do not overlap the map properly, you have a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) issue. If your map provider is Google Maps, the CRS is WGS84. Thus, you need to change the CRS of your SpatialPolygonDataFrame.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
proj4string(FieldsMap) # Gives the CRS of the data 
FieldsMap=spTransform(FieldsMap,CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")) # To convert it to WGS84
```

Then use `ggplot2::fortify(FieldsMap,byid="your id var")` to convert your SpatialPolygonDataFrame into a DataFrame, which you can use as input for `ggplot`. Beware, `fortify()` sometimes distort the polygons. If you want a simple graph, prefer the standard `plot()` function.